# how to navigate to another page from widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Am building authentication with azure using this [MSAL.JS](https://pub.dev/documentation/msal_js/latest/)
Have managed to login and get the user details. Can I redirect to another screen from the widget?

Authenticating the account and get user details

```
 Future<void> _loginPopup() async {
    try {
      final response = await widget.userAgentApplication
          .loginPopup(AuthRequest()..scopes = scopes);

      setState(() {
        _account = response.account;

      });

      print('Popup login successful. username: ${response.account.userName}');


    } on AuthException catch (ex) {
      print('MSAL: ${ex.errorCode}:${ex.errorMessage}');
    }
  }
```

this is my widget

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Web MSAL.js Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            if (_account == null) ...[
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Login Redirect'),
                onPressed: _loginRedirect,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Login Popup'),
                onPressed: _loginPopup,
              ),
            ],
            if (_account != null) ...[
              Text('Signed in as ${_account!.name}'),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Logout'),
                onPressed: _logout,
              ),
            ]
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Can I add a redirect to another page from the widget

```
if (_account != null) ...[
                  Text('Signed in as ${_account!.name}'),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Logout'),
                    onPressed: _logout,
                  ),
                ]
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, yes you can add navigation inside a scaffold widget, this is how,

define a global variable

```
  final _searchScreen = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

then call the Navigator inside the Scaffold widget like

```
 if (_account != null) ...[

              Navigator(
                key: _navScreen,
                onGenerateRoute: (route) => MaterialPageRoute(
                  settings: route,
                  builder: (context) => NavScreen(),
                ),
              ),

            ]
```

Comment: The method you use here to get the `Navigator` is required when you do not have access to the `context`. However, in your widget `build` method you do have the `context` so I prefer the simpler approach shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Screen navigation is explained in the cookbook here: [Navigate to a new screen and back](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

There are a number of options. The simplest is to navigate to the new screen widget:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextScreenWidget()),
);
```

However, if you need to navigate to the same screen in many parts of your app, this approach can result in code duplication. The solution is to define a named route, and use the named route for navigation. This is explained in the link.

Comment: Hi @Patrick ,thank you for your feedback, but this doesn't answer my question

Comment: Hi @arriff, then I am sorry that I do not understand your question, could you elaborate?

Comment: Hi @Patrick, i want to add redirect from here `if (_account != null) ...[
                  Text('Signed in as ${_account!.name}'),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Logout'),
                    onPressed: _logout,
                  ),
                ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>otherScreen()));` or use different methods fromm [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)